# Google maps search box outside map

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm playing with the Google Maps API, and I've inserted a search-form with autocomplete. The problem is that the input-box is stuck into the map. I can't display it outside the map.

```
<div style=" margin-top:100px;background: #00a6d6; width: 100%; height:100px;"><input id="address" style="position:absolute; left:1000px;"  type="text"
        placeholder="Enter a location"></div>

<div>
<div id="map-canvas" style="height:500px; width:500px;"></div></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KyMCy/1/ Watch here. I want the search-box to be in the blue container.

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't want it "stuck" to the map, don't make it a control. http://jsfiddle.net/n9nTJ/1/

Comment: @geocodezip But then, I can't use the autocomplete?

Comment: Why do you say that? http://jsfiddle.net/n9nTJ/2/

Comment: You can check this too: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

Answer (score 28):

Basically if I understand it well, you want to have an input with autocomplete that update the Google maps. But you want it outside the map

This line, is what bind your input to the map. You don't need it

```
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
```

Then you just remove the `left: 1000px` from your input and that's it.

http://jsfiddle.net/KyMCy/5/

Comment: This is the correct answer. The one by MrUpsidown actually refers to the "autocomplete" api call and not the "searchbox". There is a significant difference - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete

Comment: "The problem is that the input-box is stuck into the map. I can't display it outside the map." That's the problem I read. I think this answer is what he wanted. I vote up for the answer

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the succinct answer.

Answer (score 15):

All you need here is to load the Places library. You don't even need to display a map.

```js
new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
  (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
    types: ['geocode']
  });
```

```css
#autocomplete {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" type="text"></input>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
```

Comment: Where's the callback of search result?