# Google maps search box outside map not function

Tags: jquery, api, google-maps, maps, field

I have been looking on how to make field search box like google field search map. And I found the right answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20921378/google-maps-search-box-outside-map#_=_) which answered by @MrUpsidown. This is jsfiddle answer by @MrUpsidown [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/GVdK6/) and it works perfectly. Then I try to implement it to my project, but it does not work.

here my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>
   Search Box Map
 </title>
 <style>
   #autocomplete {
     width:300px;
   }
 </style>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=AIzaSyB1Z4LA0_Q-qH3Sfq-vIr3lShYnIwS1KUw&libraries=places" ></script>
 <script>

  function initialize() {

   new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
   (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
      types: ['geocode']
   });
  }

  initialize();

 </script>
</head>

<body>

<input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" type="text"></input>


</body>
</html>
```

I'm following the codes but still not working. Is I missing somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `initialize` **after** the DOM has been rendered.  Currently you are calling it in the head of the document before the `<input>` element exists.

Call it after the `<input>` html element is defined in the document or on the onload event (the fiddle you reference is running the JavaScript in an onload function).

```html
<style>
  #autocomplete {
    width: 300px;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=AIzaSyB1Z4LA0_Q-qH3Sfq-vIr3lShYnIwS1KUw&libraries=places"></script>
<script>
  function initialize() {

    new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
        types: ['geocode']
      });
  }
</script>

<input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" type="text"></input>
<script>
  initialize();
</script>
```

Comment: it works! I'm really new using this google map api. Thanks !